# Extending jQuery's ajax function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I want to extend the ajax function so that whenever it is called an image appears on the page that indicates there is content loading.

I can use prefilters as discussed on this page http://api.jquery.com/extending-ajax/ to show the image but how could I hide the image once the request is complete?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please have a look here: [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

These make it trivial to implement a loading image whenever an ajax request is sent through jQuery. No extending needed.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [Global Ajax Event Handlers](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/global-ajax-event-handlers/)

Using [`ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstart/) and [`ajaxStop`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/) you can control the loading image to appear when an ajax request is started, and hide it when all requests are completed, (*or a single one with [`ajaxSuccess`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsuccess/)*)

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ajaxStart`

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function(){
   //show loading imag here
 });
```

and on success remove the image

Answer (score 2):

The following code would work for you :

```
$("#loading").ajaxStart(function () { $(this).show(); }) .ajaxStop(function () { $(this).hide(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

/* show the message that data is loading on every ajax call */

```
var loadingMessage = 'Please wait loading data for ' + defaultUserName;
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#Loadstatus").bind("ajaxSend", function()
        {
            $(this).text(loadingMessage);
            $(this).show();
        }).bind("ajaxComplete", function()
        {
            $(this).hide();
        });
});
```

And, if you want to put a background image on the element with your CSS you can - animated gif is common.