# Loading image with $.ajax

Tags: jquery

I have tried [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8761713/jquery-ajax-loading-image).

This is my function, I call it when I click on the image.

```
function CheckOut(urlCheckoutNew,urlWebService) {
  var inputData = JSON.stringify(getQuotation(urlCheckoutNew));
  $('#imgloading').show();
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlWebService,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputData,
    success: function (dataQuote) {
        //alert(1);
        $('#imgloading').hide();
    }
  });
}
```

This is my html :

```
<div id="imgloading" style="display:none;">
    <img src="/Content/Images/ImageModal/loading.gif" alt="Confirming"/>
</div>
```

The function is in state `success` the alert is working, but the image is not loading.
When the alert dialog is popup, I see the loading image is loading in the background. But when I commented the alert, the image didn't show.

Could any one tell me how could I do this?

Comment: Perhaps it shows for a very brief time?

Comment: @Jack : I'm not sure too Jack.

Comment: @j08691 : I just want the image load while my function is running, and when function is completed, the loading image will hide.

Comment: How long does your function take to run? Because if the function is quick, it might be too short for the image to actually download.

Comment: Use beforeSend and complete functions in ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9471857/show-in-progress-during-http-request-long-running-execution-in-javascript-jq/9472172#9472172

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is undoubtedly loading, it's just hidden again so quickly that it never becomes fully visible.

Test it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: urlWebService,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
    dataType: 'json',
    data: inputData,
    success: function (dataQuote) {
        $('#imgloading').fadeOut(2000);
    }
});
```

The result should be that your image appears and then fades out slowly.  That's likely not your intended behavior, but it'll confirm that your image is indeed loading (since the `alert()` approach wasn't convincing...).

You might wish to show the image for a short period of time to give the user a sense of security that something is indeed happening. In that case, I would suggest delaying hiding the image somewhat.  There are numerous ways to accomplish this, but I typically do the following:

```
success: function (dataQuote) {
    var $image = $('#imgloading')
    $image.show(500, $image.fadeOut(2000));
}
```

Since the image is already shown, the `show()` is redundant and acts as a simple delay.

Comment: Yesh! that's what I want. Thanks you :)

Comment: It worked for me when I used `$('#imgloading').fadeOut(2000);`, but `$('#imgloading').show(500, fadeOut(2000));` is error (fadeOut is not a function).

Comment: @socheata I honestly don't see why you would want to have a fade in/out effect on a loading image; if it loads within 200ms then great! :)

Comment: Yes, that's great for me. I just want to tell the error to avoid next time only :)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('#imgloading').html('');
```

it will remove the html of the `#imgloading` so the image will gone

and you havent show the image

```
<div id="imgloading" style="display:none;">
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^-------its hidden already 

    <img src="/Content/Images/ImageModal/loading.gif" alt="Confirming"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, you show the image first:

```
$('#imgloading').show();
```

Then you perform the AJAX request and on success you hide it:

```
$('#imgloading').hide();
```

If the image doesn't seem to show at all, there could be a few "issues":

1. The request is synchronous, so the page doesn't get a chance to update in between.
2. The request is so fast that the image shows for only a very short time; you can wrap the `hide()` inside a `setTimeout()` to delay the hide and verify it's working properly, though you have proven that with the `alert()` as well.
3. Related to the previous, when you show the `<div>` the browser would first load the image; depending on how long that takes, by the time your request comes back it would be hidden again.